# Apache can’t connect to Unix domain socket

Tags: apache-2.4, rocky-linux, unix-sockets

I am trying to install a custom web application with Apache HTTPd as frontend web server. But why does Apache report it couldn't access the Unix socket where the application listens?

The web application is configured to listen here:

```
# ls -l /run/mt_plackup_master.sock
srwxrwxrwx. 1 apache apache 0 Jan 18 21:16 /run/mt_plackup_master.sock
```

I manually made `chown apache:apache` and `chmod 777` to grant all possible permissions on the socket file.

The `apache` user is able to access the file:

```
# su apache -s /bin/sh -c "curl --unix-socket /run/mt_plackup_master.sock --head localhost"
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: some_sub_page/
Date: Tue, 18 Jan 2022 20:21:56 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```

But Apache serves a HTTP 503 Service unavailable and writes to the error log:

```
[Tue Jan 18 21:16:32.738727 2022] [proxy:error] [pid 864514:tid 139775709259520] (13)Permission denied: AH02454: HTTP: attempt to connect to Unix domain socket /run/mt_plackup_master.sock (localhost) failed
[Tue Jan 18 21:16:32.738781 2022] [proxy_http:error] [pid 864514:tid 139775709259520] [client ::1:50532] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: httpd-UDS
```

This is with Apache 2.4.37 on Rocky Linux.

**Update:** as requested

```
# ls -Z /run/mt_plackup_master.sock 
system_u:object_r:var_run_t:s0 /run/mt_plackup_master.sock
```

Comment: Most probably selinux. Run `ls -Z` on the socket and share the output.

Comment: and what is the user that runs apache? usually for debian is www-data

Comment: On Rocky Linux the user is named `apache` as mentioned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried

```
# chcon -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /run/mt_plackup_master.sock
```

and it seems to work. Is that the right SELinux context for a web application socket? Any recommendations?